# webapi rest... is best practivce to avoid SESSION

Tags: rest, session, asp.net-web-api

I am creating my first webapi project using ExtJS for the client-side and trying to understand login procedures.  I'm trying to understand what SESSION is used for and if I use REST, SESSION should not be part of it.

*REST by design is stateless. By adding session (or anything else of that kind) you are making it stateful and defeating any purpose of having a RESTful API.
The whole idea of RESTful service is that every resource is uniquely addressable using a universal syntax for use in hypermedia links and each HTTP request should carry enough information by itself for its recipient to process it to be in complete harmony with the stateless nature of HTTP".*

I'm a bit confused on session... normally, when a user logs in the sessionID is recorded somewhere on server?  Then when user makes another request, url sends this sessionID back to server and if the ID is valid proceed with request.
Do I have this right?

On the other hand with rest the request message basically sends the username/password everytime a request is sent.

Do I have this right?  Using REST on my webapi, can I skip the whole concept of SESSION and just keep sending username/password... or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I skip the whole concept of SESSION and just keep sending
>   username/password... or is there a better way?

Yes, Web API has Token based Authorization - Bearer token. By using it, you can totally avoid using Session State.

[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

In a nut shell, when a user is successfully authenticated, server issues a token instead of session state. Then every request, the user sends the same token along with the payload.

Comment: thanks @Win.  I'll check that tutorial out.  As for the understanding of SESSION, do I understand it correctly with my description above?  also, this method, "OAuth2 Individual accounts. The app uses a membership database", this is the preferred way rather than sending username/password everytime?... and good for public audience to login to web application?

Comment: We do not send username/password everytime; it is why Microsoft has bear token already build-in to Web API *(you do not need to reinvent the wheel)*. ***FYI:** always use SSL.* Whether login or not to login is your call; I personally do not like creating an account just to read something.

Comment: thanks, then token build-in IT IS!  appreciate the information!